# bash scripting : ( data extraction ) give suggetion using awk sed grep or anything useful command

Tags: bash, data-extraction

this is part of my input file. I need to extract data. specifically, i want to extract Partial fugacity: in  unit [bar]. i have made those value bold.  show me how to do it?

```
Component 0 [hexane] (Adsorbate molecule)
    Partial pressure:      5000.00000000000000 [Pa]
                             37.50000000000000 [Torr]
                              0.05000000000000 [bar]
                              0.04934616333580 [atm]

    Fugacity coefficient:       0.9986883219 [-]

    Partial fugacity:      4993.44160943095812 [Pa]
                             37.45081207073218 [Torr]
                              ***0.04993441609431 [bar]***
                              0.04928143705335 [atm]
Component 1 [22-dimethylbutane] (Adsorbate molecule)
    Partial pressure:      5000.00000000000000 [Pa]
                             37.50000000000000 [Torr]
                              0.05000000000000 [bar]
                              0.04934616333580 [atm]

    Fugacity coefficient:       0.9988647141 [-]

    Partial fugacity:      4994.32357042947660 [Pa]
                             37.45742677822107 [Torr]
                              ***0.04994323570429 [bar]***
                              0.04929014133165 [atm]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Only 1 command:

```
awk '/fugacity/ { getline; getline; if ($2 == "[bar]") print $1 }' file.txt
```

not very clear from your question and example, but if you want just the first one

```
awk '/fugacity/ { getline; getline; if ($2 == "[bar]") {print $1; exit} }' file.txt
```

Comment: superb . still i m getting two values since i have two components. can you tell me how can i get different values for different components.?

Comment: Can you show what you are expecting to have as output?

Comment: i want only one value of partial fugacity,   0.04993441609431

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
cat {file} |grep -A 3 fugacity| grep bar| awk -F" " '{print $1}'
```

Comment: thanks ! got the data